# PHP sem_get() does not work

Tags: php, semaphore, archlinux

I am trying to use **semaphores** on php but cannot get *sem_get()* function to work. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $key = 123567;
    $maxAcquire = 1;
    $permissions = 0666;
    $autoRelease = 1;

    //it gives the error on the line below
    $semaphore = sem_get($key, $maxAcquire, $permissions, $autoRelease);
    sem_acquire($semaphore); 
    echo "hello world!";
    sem_release($semaphore);
?>
```

When I try to run it with:

```
php semaphore.php
```

It prints this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sem_get()
in   /root/semaphore.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in /root/semaphore.php on line 8
```

I am working on **Arch Linux** with **PHP 7.0.3 (cli)**. I guess the solution is so simple but I couldn't find a way to fix it. If you could help me, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I remember that for some distros (Gentoo, for example), a compile flag must be turned on in order to have it working - php usually does not get packaged with multithreading support, afaik.

Comment: Semaphore is not a default module. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php).

Answer (score 2):

Support for semaphores is not a standard feature of php.

It has to be activated via compiler `--enable-sysvsem` option when creating the php binary.

See explanation in manual: http://php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all! I uncommented the line :

```
extension=sysvsem.so
```

on *php.ini* and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The semaphore extension is not available by default, as stated in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php):

> Support for this functions are not enabled by default. To enable System V semaphore support compile PHP with the option `--enable-sysvsem` . To enable the System V shared memory support compile PHP with the option `--enable-sysvshm` . To enable the System V messages support compile PHP with the option `--enable-sysvmsg` .

If you are on a hosted server, then that hosting service probably does not offer this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php). It feels like you do not have installed php with semaphores properly. Have a look at the [installation instructions](http://php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this years later as I did. On newer RPM based systems the package name has apparently changed. In order to get the sysvsem.so module nowadays you need to install php-process:

`dnf install -y php-process`